# nodejs: use of Buffer when reading the file causes memory leak

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, buffer

I have a memory when I use the following code to copy 5mb of the file "test.mp4" to the file "test1.mp4" in response to a request from a browser.

The attached  code creates a buffer, which stores the content of the file "test.mp4" when copying it. However, I see that nodejs process eats ~10mb after each request from a browser.

I know that using streams and pipes is more appropriate for the task but I am really curious of how to implement the task using buffer.

Please help me to find the root cause of the issue.

Thank you in advance!

```
var
    fs = require("fs"),
    http = require("http"),
    os = require("os");

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    console.log("The request has been made");
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    fs.open("test.mp4", "r", function(err, fd){
        var buf = new Buffer(5000000);
        console.log("Free memory "+ os.freemem());
        fs.read(fd, buf, 0, 5000000 ,0, function(err, read){
            fs.writeFile("test1.mp4", fd, function(){
                fs.close(fd);
                buf = null;
            });
            res.write("The request has been fulfilled");
            res.end();
        });
    });
});

server.listen(80);
```

Comment: You have the wrong arguments to `fs.writeFile()`.  You need to pass the `buf` data, not `fd`  `fs.writeFile("test1.mp4", buf, ...)`  Also, need error handling on `fs.read()`.  If you had error handling on `fs.write()` you would probably be getting an error there that would have showed you this programming error.  ALWAYS have error handling on every async call.  Otherwises errors are often silently ignored leaving you to wonder why things aren't working.  I'm not sure if this is responsible for your memory usage or not, but first you need to make the code work properly.

Comment: Also, if you're just going to read the whole file into memory, why not use `fs.readFile()` which is simpler and will allocate the correct size buffer for it.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00,

Thank you a lot for your comments!
I have changed argument from "fd" to "buf". Unfortunately, nothing has changed - everything works but the memory issue is still reproducible. May be you have any other ideas?

Comment: A memory leak is only indicated if memory continues to rise over time by a somewhat constant amount.  If you run the test 10 times, see how much memory is being used, then run it 100 times and see how much memory is being used.  And, you can't really look at only the overall process memory as you  have to distinguish between memory in use by node.js vs. memory allocated by the process, but currently sitting in the free pool and available for reuse by something else.  I finer grain way of examining memory use it with a heap snapshot.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, Thanks again for the quick reply! I have run multiple times the request to the server. I have been able to see that the increasing memory used by nodejs process after each request (+10mb after a request).

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, I would be very much grateful, if you run the attached snippet and check it.

Comment: You can't identify what is leaking by looking at process memory usage.  You will need multiple heap snapshots.  I'd suggest you read several of [these articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=diagnosing+memory+leaks+in+node.js).  There are tools to use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134318/discussion-between-beninaction16-and-jfriend00).